# A better method of replacing content than str_replace?

Tags: php

I am currently using:

```
$content = $_POST['content'];
$content = str_replace("<","&lt;",$content);
$content = str_replace(">","&gt;",$content);
$content = str_replace('"',"&quot;",$content);
```

To replace characters so that I am able to show code on my website, is there a better method than doing this which will have the same result?

Comment: Yes, it's called [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities)

Comment: your question is unclear. do you want to replace stuff or show your code as code FROM your code and from user input?

Comment: This function will replace `<, >, ", and &` with their entities, http://php.net/htmlspecialchars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrays as `str_replace`'s parameters.

```
$content = str_replace(array('<', '>', '"'), array('&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot'), $_POST['content']);
```

Or use `<xmp>` tag, if you want to show HTML tags on output.

Answer (score 0):

```
highlight_string($content);
```

This will display your code highlighted. No need to replace strings.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php

Comment: I have never answered a question like this before, but we're going off-topic. I feel like you have me confused with someone else.

Comment: Apologies - a mixup on my part. Switching between too many posts.

Comment: @JayBlanchard *Blame it on the weekend Sam* ;-)

Comment: NB worth noting that highlight_string() only works with PHP code. If you want to display some other language you would need something else e.g GeSHi (a generic syntax highlighter) -- https://github.com/GeSHi

Comment: @Fred-ii- *I sure will Ralph!*